# returning an array of character

Tags: c++, arrays

When I compile I got this errors:

```
$ gcc ArraysOfCharStrings1.cpp  -lstdc++ -o ArraysOfCharStrings1 
ArraysOfCharStrings1.cpp: In function 'char* int2month(int)':
ArraysOfCharStrings1.cpp:11: error: invalid conversion from 'const char' to 'char*'
ArraysOfCharStrings1.cpp:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
```

I am trying to learn the use of arrays of character strings from a book C++ and to make this program works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// int2month() - return the name of the month
char* int2month(int nMonth)
{
    // first check for a value out of range
    if (nMonth < 1 || nMonth > 12)
    {
        const char* noGood = "invalid";
        return noGood; 

    }

    // nMonth is valid - return the name of the month
    const char* pszMonths[] = {"invalid",
                       "January",
                       "February",
                       "March",
                       "April",
                       "May",
                       "June",
                       "July",
                       "August",
                       "September",
                       "October",
                       "November",
                       "December"};

    return (pszMonths[nMonth]);
}


int main(int nArg, char* pszArgs[])
{
    const char* response = int2month(1);
    std::cout << response << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I saw others answer and tried the responses but I did not succed to make the program runs.

Comment: does it work if you change `char* int2month(int nMonth)` to `const char* int2month(int nMonth)`?

Comment: It works. Thank you

Comment: One of the best things you can do in learning to code is to read and understand the warnings and errors output by your compiler. They are actually quite good and tell you the exact line (and column) where the problematic code is found. You can learn as much C++ just by listening to what your compiler is telling you as you can from most tutorials....

Comment: array of character = string... use a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return const char* value from a char* function

```
char* int2month(int nMonth)
{

if (nMonth < 1 || nMonth > 12)
{
    const char* noGood = "invalid";
    return noGood;    //cannot return *char value
}
//other code
}
```

If you put const to your function;

```
const char* int2month(int nMonth)    //here
{

if (nMonth < 1 || nMonth > 12)
{
const char* noGood = "invalid";
return noGood;    //valid
}
//other code
}
```

It will work